# What is the reduced suspension of $I=[0,1]$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

How to visualise the reduced suspension of $I=[0,1]?$

Here is an answer, [Smash product of $S^1$ with the interval $I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291733/smash-product-of-s1-with-the-interval-i)
but I don't get it. So, it will be helpful for me if you can give a pictorial view.Thanks

Comment: Do you understand how to visualize the unreduced suspension?

Comment: Yes, that's a double cone.Right?

Comment: This depends on your choice of basepoint for $I$. For instance $\Sigma(I,0)\cong S^1\wedge(I,0)\cong D^2$, whilst $\Sigma(I,\frac{1}{2})\cong D^2\vee D^2$. ($D^2$ is the unit disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$ based at $(1,0)$). If $I$ has the basepoint $0$ (or $1$), then you should visualise its reduced suspension as a disc.

Comment: Thanks. I can see now. Now it remains to prove it. I Will try it.

Comment: Did you manage to work things out Tom?

Comment: @Tyrone, will you please check my solution?

Answer (score 0):

We claim that, $\Sigma (I,0)\cong D^2/A$ where, $A=\{(r,0):r\in [0,1]\}$
Consider the map,

$F:I\times I\to D^2/A$ given by,

$F(t,r)=[re^{2πit}]$ then $F$ is continuous.

Next, by universal mapping property and noting that , $I\times I $ is compact and $D^2/A$ is Hausdorff, we conclude that,
$I×I/\left(\{0,1\}×I\bigcup I×\{0\}\right)\cong D^2/A$ and thus our claim is proved.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but you don't need to collapse out anything (i.e. $D^2$ is homeomorphic to $D^2/A$). Note that $\Sigma(I,0)=(S^1\times I)/(S^1\times 0\cup1\times I)$ is the same thing as the reduced cone on $S^1$, and this is just $D^2$. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3740931/reduced-cone-of-sn/3741303#3741303) for instance.